# how to transfer ImageField file to multipart/form-data which will be posted by requests

Tags: django, python-requests

python3.6,I got a ImageField image in Django 2.2, how can i transfer it to multipart/form-data ,then post it with requests

I have tried requests-toolbelt, add Content-Type: Multipart/Form-data boundry=......

it returns 403
here is code:

```
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder
import requests
    multipart_encoder = MultipartEncoder(fields={
                    "api_key": self.api_key,
                    "api_secret": self.api_secret,
                    "comparison_type": comparison_type,
                    "image_ref1": (image_ref1.name.rsplit("/")[1], image_ref1.file.file, "image/" + "jpeg" if image_ref1.name[-3:] == "jpg" or image_ref1.name[-3:] == "jpeg" else "png") if image_ref1 else None,
                    "uuid": uuid,
                    "biz_no": biz_no,
                    "screen_replay": "1",
                    "biz_extra_data": str(biz_extra_data)
                })

            self.headers["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data; boundary=${bound}"
            self.headers['Content-Type'] = multipart_encoder.content_type
            if all([self.api_key, self.api_secret, return_url, notify_url, biz_no]):
                # try:
                res = requests.post(url=API_URL, headers=self.headers, data=multipart_encoder, timeout=5)
```

403 Denied, request wil be ok without image

Comment: Do you have sufficient permission to write to the target directory?

Comment: Am i rigtht to write like that? the "image_ref1" is ImageField type image  and I have the permission to write

Comment: Pleas [edit] your question add your full model definition.

Comment: it is just a request, when django project run ,I need send image which is posted by users  to API to  analyse

Comment: 403 means trouble with authorization. Recheck your api keys, secrets & urls.

Comment: Have you installed Pillow?